# How to render values in a view from Discriminator column in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Simple question - is there a way to render values from Discriminator column in my db? I have inheritance in my model and there is a Discriminator column but it's not accessible from any view like other columns. The model is generated by code-first and EF6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`SqlQuery<T>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), where T is a derived type of base class that is not an EF entity `[NotMapped]`.

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
[NotMapped]
public class PersonVm : Person
{
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }
}
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this.

```
var q = db.People.Where(x => x.Name == "Foo").ToString();
var people = db.Database.SqlQuery<PersonVm>(q).ToArray();
// var here = people[0].Discriminator;
```